# How to reduce repetition when updating GUI controls from other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

Writing a server application and my code is starting to get a bit.. repetitive.. Take a look:

```
private void AppendLog(string message)
{
    if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtLog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => txtLog.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine)));
    }
    else
    {
        txtLog.AppendText(message);
    }
}

private void AddToClientsListBox(string clientIdentifier)
{
    if (listUsers.InvokeRequired)
    {
        listUsers.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => listUsers.Items.Add(clientIdentifier)));
    }
    else
    {
        listUsers.Items.Add(clientIdentifier);
    }
}

private void RemoveFromClientsListBox(string clientIdentifier)
{
    if (listUsers.InvokeRequired)
    {
        listUsers.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => listUsers.Items.Remove(clientIdentifier)));
    }
    else
    {
        listUsers.Items.Remove(clientIdentifier);
    }
}
```

I'm using .NET 4.0. Is there still not a better way to update the GUI from other threads? If it makes any different I am using [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) to implement threading on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encapsulate the repetitive logic in another method:

```
public static void Invoke<T>(this T control, Action<T> action) 
  where T : Control {
  if (control.InvokeRequired) {
    control.Invoke(action, control);
  }
  else {
    action(control);
  }
}
```

Which you can use like so:

```
listUsers.Invoke(c => c.Items.Remove(clientIdentifier));
```

Comment: Might as well call `Invoke()` specifying the necessary arguments, you already have your delegate.  `control.Invoke(action, control);`

Comment: Is there any difference between `control.Invoke(action, control);` and `control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => action(control)));`?

Comment: @John Smith: I think his idea was to write: `control.Invoke(action, control);` in line 4 above. I'll update...